# Seleccionar span por atributo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando ocultar un `span` con el atributo `title="Planificación"` de la siguiente manera, pero no funciona y no me da error en consola

```js
$("span").find(`[title='Planificación']`).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span title="Planificación">Planificación</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `find` de jQuery funciona para buscar hijos debajo del elemento desde el cual se ejecuta esta función [jQuery FIND](https://api.jquery.com/find/). En tu caso, el elemento `SPAN` no tiene hijos con esa propiedad. Para lograr tu objetivo, debes buscar elementos SPAN con la propiedad title, que tenga el valor deseado. Ejemplo:

```js
$("span[title='Planificación']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span title="Planificación">Planificación</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con

```
$("span[title='Planificación']").hide();
```